# Cout to console SDL Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, console, sdl, cout

Before you dismiss this as a duplicate I have been searching for a solution for 2 days. I've tried every thing I found except recompiling SDLmain (I don't know how to do this). Anyways I've noticed that many solutions include opening a file :: CON

For Exapmle I believe that is what this does:

```
ofstream ctt("CON");
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
freopen( "CON", "w", stderr );
```

I am currently working on a school computer with a bunch of restrictions on it so I can't use anything other than Code::Blocks and I thought that maybe these restrictions were making it impossible for this CON file to open. So is it possible that the school filters are keeping this from working?

Some extra infomation:

When I run the program the console opens but nothing ever prints to it

Without the above lines of code stuff gets printed to stdout.

With them it doesn't get printed to anything at all.

Also I am using endl's at the end of my cout statements

Comment: What's your question? You said just using `std::cout` works? Then use that.

Comment: @chris i want it to print to the console (not stdout.txt)

Comment: `std::cout` prints to `stdout`, which is typically the console by default. There's no `stdout.txt` that we know of.